# os.path.getsize() returns "0"

Tags: python, python-3.x, os.path

Getting "0" output, when I am trying to use os.path.getsize()

Not sure what's wrong, using PyCharm, I see that the file was created and the "comments" were added to the file. But PyCharm shows the output "0" :(

Here is the code:

```
import os
def create_python_script(filename):
  comments = "# Start of a new Python program"
  with open(filename, "w") as file:
    file.write(comments)
    filesize = os.path.getsize(filename)
  return(filesize)

print(create_python_script("program.py"))
```

Please, point what is the error I don't see.

Comment: Try getting the filesize after the file is closed i.e. outside the `with open(...)`

Comment: Yes, that is work. Thank you!

Comment: use filesize = os.path.getsize(filename) outside of with context manager

Comment: Since this is resolved by unindenting `filesize`, I'm voting to close the question as caused by a typo / not reproducible.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting the size `0`, due to the peculiar behaviour of the `write` function.

When you call the `write` function, it writes the content to the `internal buffer`. An `internal buffer` is kept for performance constraints (to limit too frequent I/O calls).

So in this case, you can't ensure that the data/content has been actually dumped to the file on disk or not when you call the `getsize` function.

```
with open(filename, "w") as file:
    file.write(comments)
    filesize = os.path.getsize(filename)
```

In order to ensure that the content is dumped to the file before calling the `getsize` function, you can call `flush` method.

- `flush` method clears the internal buffer and dumps all the content to the file on the disk.

```
with open(filename, "w") as file:
    file.write(comments)
    file.flush()
    filesize = os.path.getsize(filename)
```

Or, a better way would be to first close the file and then call the `getsize` method.

```
with open(filename, "w") as file:
    file.write(comments)
filesize = os.path.getsize(filename)
```